# How to get model value using coffeescript Backbone.js Coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm unable to alert the model value from the router when I visited/navigated to the 'entries/:id' url. But in the console log i can see the variable with a correct attribute & value. I had tested to fetch the data at my chrome console & it works just fine.

inside my router:

```
class Raffler.Routers.Entries extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'
    'entries/:id': 'show'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Raffler.Collections.Entries()
    @collection.reset($('#container').data 'entries')

  index: ->
    view = new Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    entry = new Raffler.Models.Entry({id: id})
    entry.fetch()
    console.log(entry.get('title'))
    alert entry.get('name')
    console.log(entry)
    console.log(entry.attributes + " haha")
    viewsangat = new Raffler.Views.Page({model: entry})
    viewsangat.render()
```

inside my model:

```
class Raffler.Models.Entry extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: '/api/entries'

  win: ->
    @set(winner: true)
    @save()
    @trigger('highlight')
```

Solution:
I found out that the value from fetch will only available during/after on success event and therefor if we tries to use get at the next line, it will probably doesn't return the value as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Some consoles will show you the value of the object after the fetch.  Either way, the issue is that a `fetch()` is asynchronous.

```
entry = new Raffler.Models.Entry({id: id})
entry.fetch()  #HERE IS YOUR ISSUE
alert entry.get('name')  #fetch has not yet returned
```

Try the following:

```
entry = new Raffler.Models.Entry({id: id})
entry.fetch()  #HERE IS YOUR ISSUE
entry.on("reset") ->
  alert(entry.get('name'))  #fetch has not yet returned
```

If that doesn't work, change "reset" to "change".

Here you are using the [on](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on) event binding for [fetch](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch) on a model.

Comment: That is not the recommended way, but it will work.  The reason for event binding is, what if you have multiple things listening for a change on a model/collection?  The success callback can't trigger them all, and if you do, you will end up with spaghetti code.